# trying to find the biggest negative and smallest positive from given input

Tags: c#

im trying to build an algorythm which input is 10 numbers (positive and negative) and the output is the smallest positive number and the biggest negative number.
im getting the right answer for the smallest positive, but not for the biggest negative.
code and output are inserted.

[image: code]

[image: output]

Comment: please add the code the question, not as an image but as a text

Comment: You should copy paste code and output  into a question. Format it nicely. So that the question contains everything without external links and people can copy&paste it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is better to copy the code in here than linking to an image that shows the code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: You can try *Linq*: `int biggestNegative = numbers.Where(x => x < 0).Max(); int smallestPositive = numbers.Where(x => x > 0).Min();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Wouldn't that throw an exception if there are no negative numbers in the set?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a collection, say, `int[] numbers` you can just *query* it with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int[] numbers = ...

  ...

  // Either biggest negative or 0 (if we don't have any negative values)
  int biggestNegative = numbers
    .Where(x => x < 0)
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // <- we don't want exception on empty input
    .Max(); 

  // Either smallest positive or 0 (if we don't have any positive values) 
  int smallestPositive = numbers        
    .Where(x => x > 0)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()  // <- we don't want exception on empty input
    .Min();
```

If you prefer to compute the values in a `for` loop:

```
  int biggestNegative = 0; 
  int smallestPositive = 0; 

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ...
    // Simplest, you may want to check user input 
    int value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    ...
    if (value > 0) 
      smallestPositive = smallestPositive == 0 
        ? value
        : Math.Min(smallestPositive, value);
    else if (value < 0) 
      biggestNegative = biggestNegative == 0 
        ? value
        : Math.Max(biggestNegativee, value);  
  }
```

Let's print the values out:

```
Console.WriteLine(
  $"Biggest negative: {(biggestNegative == 0 ? "???" : biggestNegative.ToString())}");

Console.WriteLine(
  $"Smallest positive: {(smallestPositive == 0 ? "???" : smallestPositive.ToString())}");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Math.Min()` in both cases? -4 is bigger than -3 magnitude wise, but `Math.Max(-4, -3) == -3' instead. Or is the question incomplete?

Comment: @Tanveer Badar: no; please, check youself: `-4 < -3`; if you want `-4 > -3` rule (comparing by *absolute values*), put `: -Math.Max(Math.Abs(biggestNegativee), Math.Abs(value))`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (num>negMax)
```

There is a mistake in this condition. As your initial negMax value is 0, no negative number will meet the condition, and therefore negMax value will never be updated.

Comment: Then it's not the condition, but the start value. It should be int.MinValue. Also: What has completely overlooked here is what if there _is no negative element_ ?

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `negMax` as 0.

There is no negative number that is bigger than 0.

Depending on what exactly you want to accomplish, you could do one of the following:

- Initialize `negMax` as `int.MinValue`

This would be okay if it's guaranteed that there's at least one negative number, since the first negative input is guaranteed to be equal or greater. If negative input isn't guaranteed, you cannot tell if there were any and your output may end up incorrect.

- Modify the condition for assigning a new value to `negMax`

You could instead modify the condition for assigning a new value to `negMax` to `if (num > negMax || negMax >= 0)`.

Since you usually don't treat 0 as a negative number (and if you do, you can initialize `negMax` with any positive number instead), you'd know that there were no negative numbers if the output ends up as 0.

To do the same with `posMin`, you'd have to initialize it as something less than 0 and adjust the if-condition for assigning a value to that variable accordingly.

Alternatively, you could also declare `negMax` and `posMin` as `int?`s and check for null instead of `>= 0`.

If you choose this way, you can check the values for both variables and output, for example, that no negative or no positive numbers were entered instead of outputting whichever placeholder you chose.

Comment: That is why it _does not_ work. How would you _resolve_ the issue?

Comment: @Fildor That's hard to answer, since it's not specified what should happen in cases when there are no negative, no positive or even no numbers at all. You're right though, I should add that.